# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.blacklight.common.DBManager

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to connect my service file to cloud sql instance. But I am geeting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.blacklight.common.DBManager

Here is my class

```
package com.blacklight.common;

import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;

@WebListener("Initialize db upon initialization of application context")
public class DBManager implements ServletContextListener {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DBManager.class);

    private static final Object dataSourceLock = new Object();
    private static DataSource dataSource = null;

    static {
        dataSource = initDataSource();
    }

    private static DataSource initDataSource() {
        synchronized (dataSourceLock) {
            try  {
                String username = "aaaa";
                String password = "bbbb";

                String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
                String instance = "project-Id:location:database-name";


                if (dataSource == null) {

                    HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
                    config.setUsername(username);
                    config.setPassword(password);

                    config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql:///Features");
                    config.setUsername(username);
                    config.setPassword(password);

                    config.setDriverClassName(driverName);
                    config.setConnectionInitSql("SET NAMES 'utf8mb4'");
                    config.addDataSourceProperty("socketFactory","com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory");
                    config.addDataSourceProperty("cloudSqlInstance", instance);
                    config.addDataSourceProperty("characterEncoding", "UTF-8");
                    config.addDataSourceProperty("useUnicode", "true");
//                    config.addDataSourceProperty("noAccessToProcedureBodies", "true");

                    config.addDataSourceProperty("useSSL", "true");
                    config.addDataSourceProperty("ipTypes", "PRIVATE,PUBLIC");

                    config.setMaximumPoolSize(50);
                    config.setMinimumIdle(5);
                    config.setConnectionTimeout(10000);
                    config.setIdleTimeout(600000);
                    config.setMaxLifetime(1800000);

                    dataSource = new HikariDataSource(config);
                }
                return dataSource;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error");
                LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
            throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't initialize datasource");
        }
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        if (dataSource == null) {
            dataSource = initDataSource();
        }
        return dataSource.getConnection();
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        dataSource = initDataSource();
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        if (dataSource != null) {
            ((HikariDataSource) dataSource).close();
        }
    }

}
```

and my error logs are
com.blacklight.common.DBManager initDataSource: Failed to initialize pool: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.throwPoolInitializationException(HikariPool.java:596)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:582)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.(HikariPool.java:115)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.(HikariDataSource.java:81)
at com.blacklight.common.DBManager.initDataSource(DBManager.java:71)
at com.blacklight.common.DBManager.(DBManager.java:26)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler$StaticContext.createInstance(ContextHandler.java:2902)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler$Context.createInstance(ServletContextHandler.java:1299)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler$StaticContext.createListener(ContextHandler.java:2913)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ListenerHolder.doStart(ListenerHolder.java:94)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:369)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1449)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty94.AppEngineWebAppContext.startWebapp(AppEngineWebAppContext.java:274)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1414)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:916)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:288)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:524)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty94.AppEngineWebAppContext.doStart(AppEngineWebAppContext.java:218)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty94.AppVersionHandlerFactory.doCreateHandler(AppVersionHandlerFactory.java:207)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty94.AppVersionHandlerFactory.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerFactory.java:125)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty94.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:82)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty94.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:176)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.RequestRunner.dispatchServletRequest(RequestRunner.java:264)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.RequestRunner.dispatchRequest(RequestRunner.java:229)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.RequestRunner.run(RequestRunner.java:194)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:273)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1117)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:350)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2416)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2450)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2235)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:818)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:404)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:307)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561)
... 31 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:293)
at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
at com.google.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory.createSslSocket(CoreSocketFactory.java:275)
at com.google.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory.connect(CoreSocketFactory.java:229)
at com.google.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory.connect(CoreSocketFactory.java:188)
at com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory.connect(SocketFactory.java:41)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:300)